# Convert Date of Birth in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert the date of birth in pandas from mm/dd/yy to mm/dd/yyyy. See screenshot below:

[image: see image by clicking here. my reputation isn't a 10 yet!]

The issue im having is when converting date of birth from

```
06/13/54
04/15/70
```

to the mm/dd/yyyy format it is assuming that the date is in the 2000's. Obviously those users wouldn't even be born yet. Is there a function or something that can be used to make sure the conversion is done properly or as proper as it can be. Let's assume for this case no user lives past 90.

Comment: Please type out your code, instead of providing screenshots.

Comment: use date.today() and and set up an if else loop and please explain your code in detail

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't `strftime` back to the [very bad, not good mm-dd-yy](https://xkcd.com/1179/) format, but keep things as Pandas `datetime`s.

Either way, you can come up with a function that fixes "bad-looking" dates and `.apply()` it – this is using a single `pd.Series`, but that's what dataframes are composed of anyway, so you get the idea.

```
>>> s = pd.Series(["06/13/54", "04/15/70"])
>>> s2 = pd.to_datetime(s)
0   2054-06-13
1   2070-04-15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> def fix_date(dt):
...     if dt.year >= 2021:  # change threshold accordingly
...         return dt.replace(year=dt.year - 100)
...     return dt
...
>>> s3 = s2.apply(fix_date)
0   1954-06-13
1   1970-04-15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace the year if it is in the future?

```
x = pd.to_datetime('06/13/54',format='%m/%d/%y')
if x>datetime.datetime.now():
    x.replace(year=x.year-100)
```

Comment: Welcome - please mark as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':["06/13/54", "04/15/70"]})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%y')
df
```

**Input df**

```
    date
0   2054-06-13
1   1970-04-15
```

**Code**

```
df.date = df.date.mask(df.date.gt(pd.Timestamp('today')), df.date-pd.DateOffset(years=100))
df
```

**Output**

```
    date
0   1954-06-13
1   1970-04-15
```

Comment: Awesome this worked like a charm. I was looking for something that required the least amount of functionality and this was it !!!

Comment: Yeah, to existing wonderful answers,  added this answer  to solve the problem in ` the pandas way`.

Comment: This can be suboptimal if the df is very large, though, since `df.date - pd.DateOffset(years=100)` is eagerly computed for all dates.

Comment: I don't think so(I might be wrong), `df.date-pd.DateOffset(years=100)` will be applied only on the rows which satisfy this condition `df.date.gt(pd.Timestamp('today'))` otherwise what's the use of using `mask`.